# WCF Custom trace listener to write logs in msmq without EnterpriseLibrary

Tags: wcf, tracelistener, trace-listener

How to write custom trace listener to write message logs in msmq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added below custom MSMQTraceListener :

```
public class MSMQTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    string _queueName; 

    public MSMQTraceListener(string queueName)
        : base("MSMQListener")
    {
        _queueName = queueName;
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(_queueName))
            MessageQueue.Create(_queueName);
    }


    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        SendMessageToQueue(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        SendMessageToQueue(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send message to queue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">string: message</param>
    private void SendMessageToQueue(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue(_queueName, QueueAccessMode.Send);
            messageQueue.Label = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            messageQueue.Send(message);
            messageQueue.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And updated below diagnostic setting in my web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages" type="Proj.Common.Diagnostics.MSMQTraceListener,Proj.Common" initializeData=".\private$\PerformanceTesting" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are in code hosted by MSMQ and want to write a message to say a log file**
All .NET applications are the same as far as System.Diagnostics is concerned. Configure the listener in app.config, and use Trace or TraceSource to write to the listener. [MSDN explains this better than I can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984(v=vs.110).aspx).

**If you want a trace listener that sends message to MSMSQ**
Get this utility library, [Essential Diagnostics](https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com), that makes working with System.Diagnostics less painful

Override the one TraceEvent() method on [BaseTraceListener](https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Essential.Diagnostics/Diagnostics/TraceListenerBase.cs). Inside that method, you use the available parameters to send messages to whatever you'd like, for example an MSMQ destination.

Register your custom TraceListener in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewMartin, the points you have  mentioned are very helpful. 
To fulfill my requirement I wrote custom listener as given in my answer.